# div text is not updating on javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var now = new Date().getTime();
var remainingSeconds = (new Date(new Date(new Date(now + 3600000).setMinutes(1)).setSeconds(0)) - now) / 1000;
console.log(remainingSeconds);
if (remainingSeconds>=120) {
    $('#countdown').text('120');
}else{
    $('#countdown').text(remainingSeconds);
}
```

I use this code to calculate how many seconds there are between now and the first minute of next hour. 
The point is that the div text is not changing if remainingSeconds is less than 120 seconds. The script is in the document ready 'cause I only check it on page load.
I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leliofa/41j3mr83/) for this.

Comment: The code is working on my browser. Are you missing something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that `remainingSeconds` never gets below `60` in your code. Here is an updated version that includes a workaround/solution.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var remainingSeconds = (new Date(new Date(new Date(now + 3600000).setMinutes(1)).setSeconds(0)) - now) / 1000;
    // --- Workaround-Begin ---
    if ( remainingSeconds >= 3600 ) {
        remainingSeconds -= 3600;
    }
    // --- Workaround-End ---
    console.log(remainingSeconds);
    if (remainingSeconds>=120) {
        $('#countdown').text('120');
    }else{
        $('#countdown').text(remainingSeconds);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why you check if it is >= 3600? it is in seconds. Or I miss something?

Comment: because you try to estimate the remaining seconds until the first minute of the next hour (for example: _08:01:00_ , format: `hh:mm:ss` ). And if the current time is _08:00:20_ we would get the remaining seconds to the next hour (_09:01:00_). so we substract on hour from our result if it is larger than one hour.

Comment: I see! Thanks, didn't notice the bug! Thank you for pointing out!